# Kendo UI Editor Duplicating

Tags: asp.net, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I have a kendo grid with the following command below. When I first click on the command button, it works fine and there is 1 `<input>`, 1 `<textarea>` and 1 `<input>`. When I close the popup window and reopen it, the `<textarea>` is duplicated every time.

```
command: [{
    name: "Edit",
    title: "Alert Email",
    width: "180px",
    click: onDataBound75
}],
```

Calling the following function:

```
function onDataBound75(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#txtAlert").kendoEditor({
        resizable: {
            content: true,
            toolbar: true,
            encoded: false
        }
    });
    var window = $("#emailAlert_popup").kendoWindow({
        width: "600px",
        visible: false,
        modal: true,
        actions: [
            "Maximize",
            "Close"
        ],
    });
    var dataItem = this.dataItem($(e.currentTarget).closest("tr"));
    var viewModelAlert75 = kendo.observable({
        Alert75EmailSubject: dataItem.Alert75EmailSubject,
        Alert75EmailBody: dataItem.Alert75EmailBody,
        Alert75FromAddress: dataItem.Alert75FromAddress,
    });
    kendo.bind($("#emailAlert_popup"), viewModelAlert75);
    window.data("kendoWindow").center().open();
};
```

And the aspx file looks like this:

```
<div id="emailAlert_popup" class="TT_PopupWindow">
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtAlert75EmailSubject" style="width:200px">Email Subject</label>
        <input name="txtEmailSubject" id="txtAlert75EmailSubject" class="k-textbox" style="width:430px"
            data-bind="value: Alert75EmailSubject" />                    
    </div>
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtAlert75EmailBody" style="width:200px">Email Body</label>
        <textarea id="txtAlert" rows="10" cols="30" style="height:440px" aria-label="editor" data-bind="value: Alert75EmailBody"></textarea>
    </div>
    <div class="SearchParam">
        <label class="control-label" for="txtAlert75FromAddress" style="width:200px">From Address</label>
        <input name="txtFromAddress" id="txtAlert75FromAddress" class="k-textbox" style="width:430px"
            data-bind="value: Alert75FromAddress"
        />
    </div>
    <div class="k-edit-buttons k-state-default">
        <button type="button" id="btnAlert75EmailUpdate" data-role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-primary k-grid-update" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="0" style="float:right"><span class="k-icon k-i-check"></span>Update</button>
        <button type="button" id="btnAlert75Cancel" data-role="button" class="k-button k-button-icontext k-grid-cancel" role="button" aria-disabled="false" tabindex="1" style="float:right"><span class="k-icon k-i-cancel"></span>Cancel</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that when you open the window for the second time or more, it's contents are already created so your are creating another kendoEditor over and existing one. Try this:

```
if (!$("#txtAlert").data("kendoEditor")) {
    $("#txtAlert").kendoEditor({
        resizable: {
            content: true,
            toolbar: true,
            encoded: false
        }
    });
}
```

The above condition checks whenever the window will open, if the textarea is already an editor.

Comment: @RodneyWilson that is a common problem with the kendo window. I'm used to destroy the whole widget and it's DOM because of that problem.